# Disable scrolling just for user

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to create a page which cannot be scrolled by the user (means, no mousewheel, no space, no cursor-down etc.). while the site itself stays able to scroll: if a specific event is fired, i.e a button is triggered, the scroll should happen.

I have done a little research, not only here on stackoverflow but in different forums. There were rumors that this isn't possible and the way to achieve the disable-scroll-thing would be `overflow:hidden`

Well, this is wrong for me: http://fk-agency.com/

Does anyone know how this is done?

My personal approach would be:

Create a site whichs height is just 100% of the viewport size, then slideIn the other div's by css animation or jQuery. But it seems to hacky to me.

**EDIT**:

I tried it with the `overflow:hidden` attribute, but got the issue that scrolling won't work.

Here is a live example of my project, excluding just the necessary code will follow:

[Example](http://www.antaw.de/Bewerbung2)

And here's one without overflow:hidden

[Example 2](http://www.antaw.de/be)

**Edit #2**

I have no idea why, but suddenly it works.

I applied `overflow: hidden` to `body` and then used the following script to scroll to an element by specify it's id. All good. Many thanks to lukasgeiter, who mentioned this issue.

**Script**

```
function scroll(target){
// target should be like "#id"
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 500);

    }
```

Comment: checked the CSS of the link you provided.. There is `overflow: hidden`.. (div#video_jwplayer_display)

Comment: @Mr_Green no the relevant `overflow: hidden` is on `html`

Comment: @lukasgeiter yes that is true... but it is being applied even to `div#video_jwplayer_display` right?  (my way of saying was different, poor english) :)

Comment: @Mr_Green Of course but it has not much to do with the question, since it is just used on the first page...

Comment: that is corrdct, sorry for my unprecise question. i forgot to mention that i tried this way, but got an issue with the onclick-scrolling. I'll add a post in the next few minutes where i provide my code.

Comment: @Sprottenwels Im using Chrome in version 23 and it works fine. I click on the arrow and the page scrolls down (to a more or less empty page, but it scrolls)

Comment: @lukasgeiter same chrome here, and yup, indeed, it scrolls. but that page should not be empty. I've added a working example without overflow:hidden :)

Comment: ok thats a problem. but unfortunately i cant help you atm. if you still got this problem in 6-7 hours ill take a closer look at it

Comment: I would appreciate that very much, thank you for your efforts. If i find a solution, i will defintely post it here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22079/discussion-between-lukasgeiter-and-sprottenwels)

Answer (score 3):

For me it was possible using `overflow:hidden;` And this site is done exactly that way...
If this is not enough and scrollwheel/arrow/space still work, you have to setup handlers for the different keys and the scrollwheel and then use `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` to block them.

For example:

```
$(window).on("mousewheel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```